# Poison Ivy or Spider Bite?

Tags: coloration-discoloration, itching, rash, spider-bites

My wife and I were exposed to poison ivy last Saturday (7/16). I have more rashes that her but she has this rash that keeps expanding, picture below.

The small oval with the dark spots showed up immediately. By Tuesday the itch had began. Each day the big red circle has been gotten larger. At first the dark spots were black and looked like black-spot poison ivy.

Could this be a spider bite or a bad case of poison ivy?

[image: a busy cat]

Comment: My guess is poison ivy, and guesses are all you can expect. Spider bites are vastly overestimated by almost everyone. They're actually rather unusual. https://arthropodecology.com/2012/02/15/spiders-do-not-bite/

Comment: Hi, while this question is not necessarily personal, it is asking for a diagnosis of sorts. Your best luck would be to consult your doctor. Please consult the help center or ask here for more questions. Thank you!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Doc-In-Box diagnosed as Cellulitis from poison ivy and gave steroid shot and antibiotics prescription.

Comment: What do I win for guessing right?  ;-)

Comment: I'm not sure @CareyGregory, but whoever down voted this loses because it is an answer to the original question.

Comment: I didn't downvote it, but the question is actually off topic and that may be the reason for the downvote. Requests for personal medical advice are considered off topic here, and asking us to identify a skin lesion falls squarely in that category.

Comment: Gotcha. Thanks for your help @CareyGregory.